# Sitecore - WFFM - Cascading Drop Lists

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

Sitecore 7.5 (rev. 1141003)

I have two drop lists. One has a list of parent values. And, the second drop list has a list of child values. When the form loads, the child drop list is not visible. After a selection is made in the parent drop list, the child drop list appears and lists only the children related to the selection in the parent drop list. I am able to see the form in the Sitecore admin under the content item. When I select the form and open the Form Designer I can see the parent and child drop lists each have list items set by "Selecting Sitecore items". These values are in a section under content called MetaData. Their value and text are identical. Neither the parent or the child have any rules defined.

Where in the Sitecore admin are the settings to give these two drop lists their cascading behaviour? I would expect it to be on the Form Designer somewhere, but it is not there.

Comment: There isn't. It is either custom functionality or controlled using Javascript (which is the more common case).

Comment: @jammykam Did you want to put that as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting cascading fields is not available out of the box with the WFFM module. It is either custom functionality, or more likely the usual way of creating this kind of functionality is to use Javascript. Check if there are any custom css classes set on the drop lists and then check the Javascript for references to this css class to figure out the which JS function is attached to it.